# Arcpy geoprocessing script running with default inputs

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service

I have a pretty simple geoprocessing script. My javascript is supposed to be passing it a list of layers to query. Something like this for the Javascript:

```
var params = { "Layers": "foo,bar,hello,world"};
var gp = new Geoprocessor(*myURL*);
gp.submitJob(params, gpSuccess, gpStatus, gpFailed);
```

The Geoprocessor just explodes the list based on the comma, and reads the layers from the database. Pretty straight forward. I'm reading the inputs in as a text string, like so:

```
layers = GetParameterAsText(0)
```

My code works fine in my own testing, the problem is when I have this running as a service, I can't seem to pass it the correct values. It always runs based off the default values (which end up being whatever I supplied when I did my test run in Arc Catalog). I have "layers" defined as an input variable for the model, so I'm not sure why it's not getting my input. Checking the job status verifies that it is running off the default values, and not what I am attempting to supply as an argument.

The geoprocessing script can be accessed through the REST interface [here](https://arcgis.lsa.umich.edu/arcpub/rest/services/IFR/Criteria/GPServer/Criteria).

The source code can be found [here](https://repl.it/BpmH/0).

Comment: Are you able to post the entire geoprocessing script, and/or provide a link to the online service (_myURL_ above)?

Comment: Sure, I'll do that ASAP but I'm afraid neither are particularly clean. Should be up tomorrow morning.

Comment: Added links to the public online service and the source code for the script. Both are probably sloppy. I regret nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Geoprocessing service from the same script, available [here](https://arcgis.lsa.umich.edu/arcpub/rest/services/IFR/NewCriteria/GPServer/New%20Criteria) (Yes, I'm extremely good at naming services). I didn't do anything different (I used all the same configuration settings) but it appears to be working correctly now. My guess is there was an issue with the settings, but I honestly have no clue what it could be.

I'm not going to accept this as an answer because while it worked it certainly doesn't explain how or why this problem occurred, but it might help others in a similar situation. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable can shed some light on this eventually.

Comment: error message haiku: _yesterday it worked / today it isn't working / software is like that_

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that my geoservice kept running with default value for one of service parameters. In my case, it takes two parameters: a string list (`GPMultiValue:GPString`) and a numeric value (`GPLinearUnit`). Here are their descriptions:

```
Parameter: ConfirmedCaseUIDList
Data Type: GPMultiValue:GPString
Display Name ConfirmedCaseUIDList
Description: Confirmed Case UID List
Direction: esriGPParameterDirectionInput
Default Value: [ 20032823330760 ]
Parameter Type: esriGPParameterTypeRequired
Category:

Parameter: SearchRadius
Data Type: GPLinearUnit
Display Name SearchRadius
Description: Search Radius
Direction: esriGPParameterDirectionInput
Default Value: 1.5   (esriMeters)
Parameter Type: esriGPParameterTypeRequired
Category:
```

And my codes are like:

```
var list = ["12345","67890"];
var dist = 3;
var params = {
            "ConfirmedCaseUIDList": list,
            "SearchRadius": {
                "distance": dist,
                "units": "esriMeters"
            }
        };

gp.submitJob(params).then(drawResultData, errBack, progTest);
```

The service did take the value I feed in for the string list parameter, but kept using the default value (here is 1.5) for the second parameter, whose data type was `GPLinearUnit`.

After long trying that didn't work with the problem, I changed its data type to `GPDouble` and my codes as follows:

```
Parameter: SearchRadius
Data Type: GPDouble
Display Name SearchRadius
Description: Search Radius
Direction: esriGPParameterDirectionInput
Default Value: 1.5
Parameter Type: esriGPParameterTypeRequired
Category:

var list = ["12345","67890"];
var dist = 3
var params = {
            "ConfirmedCaseUIDList": list,
            "SearchRadius": dist
};

gp.submitJob(params).then(drawResultData, errBack, progTest);
```

The problem was solved.